# Swift- Creating a profile page like Twitter or Instagram through PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a TableView subclassed as a PFQueryTableViewController and I want to know how I can retrieve an inventory of users post from Parse. I'm having trouble receiving the users data and displaying with my code. Is there something I need to edit in my queryForTable, change in parse or change in my code?

Here is my ProfileViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class ProfileViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{

    var profilePosts:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "Test"
        self.textKey = "postMessage"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.objectsPerPage = 200

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
        query.limit = 200;

        return query
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject? {
        var obj : PFObject? = nil
        if(indexPath.row < self.objects!.count){
            obj = self.objects![indexPath.row] as? PFObject
        }

        return obj
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return profilePosts.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, object:PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! ProfileCell

        if let profilePost : PFObject = self.profilePosts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as! PFObject {

            cell.NameProfile.text = object["account"] as? String
            cell.messageProfile.text = object["postMessage"] as? String
            let dateUpdated = object.createdAt! as NSDate
            let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormat.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"

            cell.timeProfile.text =  NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String
            cell.messageProfile.numberOfLines = 0
            let likeScore = object[("count")] as! Int
            cell.likeScoreProfile.text = "\(likeScore)"
            let replyscore = object["replies"] as! Int
            cell.replyScoreProfile.text = "\(replyscore) replies"
            cell.messageProfile.text = profilePost.objectForKey("postMessage") as? String
            if let profilePic = object["profilePhoto"] as? PFFile {
                let imageView = cell.profilePhoto as PFImageView

                imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profileImg")
                imageView.file = profilePic

                imageView.loadInBackground(nil) 
            }


        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign your `profilePosts` to the `objects` that are returned from parse. You have two options for fixing this. One is to just stick with the default parse implementation of objects which allows you to use `objects` whenever you need one of your database objects. The other is to stick with your `profilePosts` array and assign it in `objectsDidLoad` which would prevent you from having to change any code except for that. Otherwise in your methods like  `numberOfRowsInSection` you would need to return `objects!.count` instead.

In the case that you decide to use your own array of `profilePosts` you'll want to do this:

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class ProfileViewController: PFQueryTableViewController{

var profilePosts:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.parseClassName = "Test"
    self.textKey = "postMessage"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 200

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError?) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    profilePosts = NSMutableArray(array: objects!)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Test")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username)
    query.limit = 200;

    return query
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> PFObject? {
    var obj : PFObject? = nil
    if(indexPath.row < self.profilePosts.count){
        obj = self.profilePosts[indexPath.row] as? PFObject
    }

    return obj
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return profilePosts.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> PFTableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PCell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as! ProfileCell

    if let object : PFObject = self.profilePosts.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as? PFObject {

        cell.NameProfile.text = object["account"] as? String
        cell.messageProfile.text = object["postMessage"] as? String
        let dateUpdated = object.createdAt! as NSDate
        let dateFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = "MMM d, h:mm a"

        cell.timeProfile.text =  NSString(format: "%@", dateFormat.stringFromDate(dateUpdated)) as String
        cell.messageProfile.numberOfLines = 0
        let likeScore = object[("count")] as! Int
        cell.likeScoreProfile.text = "\(likeScore)"
        let replyscore = object["replies"] as! Int
        cell.replyScoreProfile.text = "\(replyscore) replies"
        cell.messageProfile.text = profilePost.objectForKey("postMessage") as? String
        if let profilePic = object["profilePhoto"] as? PFFile {
            let imageView = cell.profilePhoto as PFImageView

            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "profileImg")
            imageView.file = profilePic

            imageView.loadInBackground(nil) 
        }


    return cell
}
```

Notice how I changed `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to use the object you were getting from `profilePosts` and then how I overrode `objectsDidLoad` and assigned the `PFQueryTableView` `objects` property to your `profilePosts` array. One reason you may want to do this is because by having your own managed copy of the Parse objects you can perform things like insertion or deletion with animation, which the regular `objects` property does not allow you to do. Hopefully this helps you out, let me know if you have more questions.

**EDIT 2**
In light of your comment about your more specific question, I would suggest that you edit your original question to specify that you are asking about how to get just the current user's objects, and not about which implementation to use. I am leaving that code above in there however, because the `queryForTable` method has been modified to show what you need to do to meet your query demands. It also does show those that come looking how to properly retrieve objects if they are having issues.

Comment: The data of the current user is not displaying. How does this retrieve the current users objects from the objectId?

Comment: You are using both `objects` which is stored property on `PFTableViewController` that represents the objects retrieved from Parse, but you're also using `profilePosts` which is an array that you think you should be using to represent your Parse objects, but that you never actually assign to anything. So your options are to either **only** use the property `objects` that you already have, or change your code to use only `profilePosts`, which you'll have to assign in `objectsDidLoad`

Comment: @Cooni also updated my answer to give you a better idea of what I was talking about.

Comment: Sorry i didn't phrase my question well before in the previous comment. I understand why I need to implement either of those solutions. My concern is will it display the current users objects? I'm asking because I have a HomeViewController querying all the users objects and I'm currently using the same parseClassName in both viewControllers. So I just want to know if I am not going to be querying all the same objects in the HomeViewController.

Comment: Yes you have the right parameters on your query to just get the current user's objects. Actually it should be `query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)`